# I need to draw lines on HTML canvas from the provided lat/long

Tags: javascript, canvas, geojson

I am having Below lat/log

```
[
    [26.680863912523936, -80.1179154920308],
    [26.680835153186823, -80.11685065504936],
    [26.679931626985823, -80.11687479493054],
    [26.679979559590112, -80.11796108958417]
]
```

I pick these lat/long of a squarish building from google map. Now I want to project same shape on canvas from lat/long without using any map api.

I tried various methods but they didn't work. Like

```
function projectLatLongToScreen(latitude, longitude) {
        const scaleFactorX = canvas.width / 360;
        const scaleFactorY = canvas.height / 180;

        const x = (longitude + 180) * scaleFactorX;
        const y = canvas.height - (latitude + 90) * scaleFactorY;
        
        return { x, y };
}
```

and I am receiving below coordinates.

```
{x: 221.96018779548712,y: 211.06378695825356}
{x: 221.96255409989033,y: 211.06388282271058}
{x: 221.96250045570991,y: 211.06689457671393}
{x: 221.96008646759074,y: 211.0667348013663}
```

As you can observe the x,y is having very less difference so a proper square is not drawn on canvas.

I am doing something wrong while converting lat/long into x,y coordinates which helps to draw it on HTML canvas

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Manual Projection</title>
    <style>
        canvas {
            border: 1px solid #000;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<canvas id="myCanvas" width="800" height="600"></canvas>

<script>
    const coordinates = [
        { latitude: 26.680863912523936, longitude: -80.1179154920308 },
        { latitude: 26.680835153186823, longitude: -80.11685065504936 },
        { latitude: 26.679931626985823, longitude: -80.11687479493054 },
        { latitude: 26.679979559590112, longitude: -80.11796108958417 }
    ];

    const canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
    const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    // Function to manually project lat/long to screen coordinates
    function projectLatLongToScreen(latitude, longitude) {
        const scaleFactorX = canvas.width / 360;
        const scaleFactorY = canvas.height / 180;

        const x = (longitude + 180) * scaleFactorX;
        const y = canvas.height - (latitude + 90) * scaleFactorY;
        
        return { x, y };
    }
        
    // Draw points on the canvas
    coordinates.forEach(coord => {
        const screenCoordinates = projectLatLongToScreen(coord.latitude, coord.longitude);
        console.log(screenCoordinates)
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(screenCoordinates.x, screenCoordinates.y, 5, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
        ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
        ctx.fill();
    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You've done everything right in terms of calculation - the problem is scale. You're trying to get the entire globe (360° x 180°) into a small screen! The original coordinates themselves are very small changes (0.001). Lower your endpoints from 360 & 180 down to much smaller, and your co-ordinates will come out bigger on the screen. Of course, then you will have the problem of needing to scroll for other co-ordinates - but one step at a time.

Comment: You are right, problem is scaling and I am looking for its solution. I added running sample code. Can you please checkout that one?

Comment: I can confirm that it shows a red dot / circle, yes. Give the scale problem some careful thought, and I'm sure you'll come up with a nice answer and won't need us any more :)